# (Ruby on Rails beginner) Referencing another model within a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

```
class Prescription < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user

 validates :time, presence:true
 validates :user_id, presence:true

 #I want to access an attribute from the user model, but this does not work:
 num = self.user.mobilephone

END
```

As you can see, I am using ActiveRecord and have the `belongs_to` association, so shouldn't accessing user attributes be easy?

Comment: @user313330 Add more details with your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is.

```
p = Prescription.find(1) # Assuming you have a record with an ID of 1
p.user.first_name #=> "Fred" Assuming you have a field in user called first_name
```

You may also refer to your user from with in the model

```
class Prescription < ActiveRecord::Base

   def user_full_name
     "#{self.user.first_name} #{self.user.last_name}"
   end

end
```

So really the question is how does Rails do this? The answer is meta programming. Meta programming is a complex topic within ruby. Put simply meta programming allows classes and objects to have methods added to them at run time. When your model loads it sees that you have a belongs to user defined. This will then in turn create the .user method in the above example. The method it's self will return the User model instance that is associated with the current Prescription object. Other active record methods do similar things such as has_many, has_one and has_and_belongs_to_many.

Comment: I tried accessing using self.user.first_name but it did't work. It said the "user" part was undefined.

Comment: Is the user set in the database?  Can you post the code your using as well as the error message your getting.

Comment: I updated my code. The error I am getting is "TypeError: superclass mismatch for class User"

Comment: turned out to be a stupid gem had a "User" class which was overshadowing the one I wanted. Jeez

Comment: Plivo. It's a gem that can send text messages.